# CMake output name for dynamic-loaded library?

Tags: python, cmake, shared-libraries, boost-python

I'm trying to write cmake rules to build dynamic-loaded library for python using boost.python on linux. I'd like to use 'foo' for python module name. So, the library must be called `foo.so`.
But by default, cmake uses standard rules for library naming, so if I write

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp)
```

I will get `libfoo.so` on output.
Even `set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "foobar")` 
will create `libfoobar.so`.

How to change this behavior?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can unset the prefix with this line:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Answer (score 1):

The prefix "lib" is a convention for unix/linux and is exploited widely by compilers (e.g. when you link you write -lfoo).

I don't know if you can force cmake to create foo.so instead of libfoo.so, but maybe you can use "libfoo" for python module. Another option is to create install target in cmake ,which will renmae libfoo.so to foo.so